# Sed command printing out full line

Tags: unix

Im having trouble with sed in UNIX. I would like print out every instance of the letter I, but instead this command prints out the full line everytime it finds an I. Any suggestions?
For Example: if the line is "There is something that I want" I would like it to just print out I instead of the full line.

```
find | sed -nE '/\bI\b/p' file.txt
```

Comment: Why are you using both pipe and file argument?

Comment: I am using both pipe and file arguments because I am searching for the string inside the file 'file.txt'

Comment: That explains why you have the `file.txt` argument, but does not explain why you are executing `find` at all.

Comment: Do you want to look where `file.txt` can be found? Something like `find . -name file.txt` and look for `I` in al the found files?

Answer (score 0):

Because it is what you are telling it to do:

- `-n` means don't print lines by default
- `/\bI\b/` means match a separate letter `I`
- `p` means print the line that matched the previous pattern

Maybe this is what you want, matching everything but `I` and replacing it with nothing:

```bash
]$ echo "xIxIxIx" | sed 's/[^I]//g'
III
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the complement option in `tr`.

```
echo "There is something that I want" | tr -cd 'I'
```

When you want to find `I` in different files, you can combine with `find`:

```
find . -type f -name file.txt -exec cat {} + | tr -cd 'I'
```